# Generalized Krylov subspaces and two associated values

Tags: linear-algebra

The following: What I have is a matrix $A\in\Bbb C^{N\times N}$ and a subspace $F\subset\Bbb C^N$. Define the subspaces
$$
F_n := F + AF + \dots + A^nF.
$$
Then $F=F_0\subset F_1\subset\ldots$. Also, if $F_{n+1} = F_n$, then $F_{n+k} = F_n$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$. Let $\nu$ be the smallest $n$ such that $F_{n+1} = F_n$. Also, let $p$ be the monic polynomial that is the greatest common divisor of all monic polynomials $q$ with $q(A)F = \{0\}$. Let $d$ be its degree.

What I would like to  have is a relationship between $\nu$ and $d$. For $\dim F=0$ we have $\nu = d = 0$. If $\dim F= 1$, then $d = \nu + 1$. In general, I can show $d\ge \nu + 1$. Indeed, if $p(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{d}\alpha_kz^k$ with $\alpha_k\in\Bbb C$, $k=0,\ldots,d$, $\alpha_{d} = 1$, then $\sum_{k=0}^{d}\alpha_kA^kf = 0$ for each $f\in F$. Hence, for each $f\in F$ we have
$$
A^{d}f = -\sum_{k=0}^{d-1}\alpha_kA^kf\,\in\,F_n,
$$
that is, $A^{d}F\subset F_{d-1}$, which implies $F_{d-1} = F_d$ and therefore $\nu\le d-1$.

Can anyone say more?

Comment: Coward downvoter, step forward and tell me why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easier writing, let me **redefine $v$**. Let $v = 0$ when $\dim F=0$ and $v$ as the smallest $n>0$ such that $F_n = F_{n-1}$ otherwise. Then we have $$0\leq\nu\leq d\leq N$$ The last inequality comes from [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) that the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is a polynomial of degree $N$.

Well, **we cannot say any more without further information** about $N, A$ and $F$ since for any integer $N$, $d$ and $\nu$ such that $0\leq\nu\leq d\leq N$, there exists a matrix $A\in\Bbb C^{N\times N}$ and a subspace $F\subset\Bbb C^N$ having the corresponding $v$ and $d$. For example, let $A=\text{diagonal}(1,2,\cdots, N)$ and $F=\{a(1e_1 + 2e_2 + \cdots + \nu e_{\nu})+ a_{\nu+1}e_{\nu+1} + a_{\nu+2}e_{\nu+2} + \cdots + a_de_d| a, a_{\nu+1}, a_{\nu+2}, \cdots, a_d \in \Bbb C\}$, where $e_1, e_2, \cdots, e_N$ is the standard basis of $\Bbb C^N$(as column vectors). We can check that $F_{\nu-2}\neq F_{\nu-1} = F_\nu$ and $p(x) =\prod_{1\leq i\leq d}(x-i).$  In fact, if we also know the Jordan normal form of $A$ (as an endomorphism) on $F_\nu$, then $d$ will be the sum of the largest sizes of Jordan blocks of each eigenvalue of $A$. However, all relationship between $\nu$ and $d$ we can have is the same inequality, $\nu\leq d.$

On the other hand, we can observe one related fact without more information. The expanding rate of $F_j$ is not increasing as $j$ increase. That is, **$\mathbf{\dim F_1 - \dim F_0, \dim F_2 - \dim F_1,\cdots}$, is a non-increasing sequence of integers**.

Comment: First of all, thank you! The last fact you mention I figured out by myself already. In your example, $F$ has dimension $\dim F = d-\nu+1$. I actually wondered whether one always has $d\le(\nu-1)+\dim F$. Here I use your definition of $\nu$. The guy in parentheses is my $\nu$. What do you think?

Comment: What I can show is that $p$ is actually the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $A$ to $F_{\nu-1}$. In particular,$$d\le \dim F_{\nu-1} = \dim F + \sum_{k=1}^{\nu-1}(\dim F_{k}-\dim F_{k-1}).$$

Comment: I just figured out that this is not true. A counterexample is given by$$A = \operatorname{diag}(1,2,3,4)\quad\text{and}\quad F = \operatorname{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\,,\,\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right\}.$$Then $F+AF = \Bbb C^4$, $d=4$, $\nu = 2$, and $\dim F = 2$. Hence, $(\nu-1)+\dim F = 3 < 4 = d$.